Not able to mention/use bot in a message without adding it
I’ve developed a Microsoft Teams bot that is supposed to receive and respond to messages when mentioned, like @rewards add +2 points. However, I’ve encountered an issue where I need to manually add the bot to each conversation for it to work.
In contrast, I’ve noticed that bots available on the Microsoft Teams marketplace, such as Bonusly, can be mentioned and interacted with anywhere in Teams without needing to be added to each thread manually.
I’m wondering if this behavior is due to the bot not being published on the marketplace yet, or if it’s related to how the manifest.json is configured. Could someone explain what might be causing this difference and what steps I should take to ensure my bot behaves like the marketplace bots?
Here are some specifics:
The bot is currently in development and not published on the marketplace.
The manifest.json has been set up to allow bot interactions.
Any insights on how to make my bot accessible across Teams channels and conversations without manual additions would be greatly appreciated!
Here is my manifest.json
    {
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.16/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
    "manifestVersion": "1.16",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "id": "${{TEAMS_APP_ID}}",
    "packageName": "com.microsoft.teams.extension",
    "developer": {
        "name": "Teams App, Inc.",
        "websiteUrl": "https://www.example.com",
        "privacyUrl": "https://www.example.com/privacy",
        "termsOfUseUrl": "https://www.example.com/termofuse"
    },
    "icons": {
        "color": "color.png",
        "outline": "outline.png"
    },
    "name": {
        "short": "Rewards${{APP_NAME_SUFFIX}}",
        "full": "Full name for Rewards"
    },
    "description": {
        "short": "Short description of Rewards",
        "full": "Full description of Rewards"
    },
    "accentColor": "#FFFFFF",
    "bots": [
        {
            "botId": "${{BOT_ID}}",
            "scopes": [
                "personal",
                "team",
                "groupchat"
            ],
            "supportsFiles": false,
            "isNotificationOnly": false,
            "commandLists": [
                {
                    "scopes": [
                        "personal",
                        "team",
                        "groupchat"
                    ],
                    "commands": [
                        {
                            "title": "helloWorld",
                            "description": "A helloworld command to send a welcome message"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "authorization": {
        "permissions": {
            "resourceSpecific": [
                {
                    "type": "Application",
                    "name": "ChannelMessage.Read.Group"
                },
                {
                    "type": "Application",
                    "name": "ChatMessage.Read.Chat"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "webApplicationInfo": {
        "id":  "${{BOT_ID}}",
        "resource": "https://Anthing"
    },
    "composeExtensions": [],
    "configurableTabs": [],
    "staticTabs": [],
    "permissions": [
        "identity",
        "messageTeamMembers"
    ],
    "validDomains": []
}


The Scopes in the manifest which include personal, team, and groupchat is mentioned and interact in various contexts to the bot.
Check that the bot framework setup supports mention handling and also needs to parse the incoming messages for mentions and respond accordingly.
manifest:
"bots": [
    {
        "botId": "${{BOT_ID}}",
        "scopes": [
            "personal",
            "team",
            "groupchat"
        ],
        "supportsFiles": false,
        "isNotificationOnly": false,
        "commandLists": [
            {
                "scopes": [
                    "personal",
                    "team",
                    "groupchat"
                ],
                "commands": [
                    {
                        "title": "helloWorld",
                        "description": "A helloworld command to send a welcome message"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
],

const { ActivityHandler, MessageFactory } = require('botbuilder');

class MyBot extends ActivityHandler {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.onMessage(async (context, next) => {
            const text = context.activity.text;
            const botMention = `<at>${context.activity.recipient.name}</at>`; // Adjust for your bot’s name

            if (text.includes(botMention)) {
                const command = text.replace(botMention, '').trim();
                await context.sendActivity(`You mentioned me! Command received: ${command}`);
            } else {
                await context.sendActivity('Hello! How can I assist you?');
            }

            await next();
        });
    }
}

module.exports.MyBot = MyBot;


Navigate to Teams apps > Setup policies. Modify policy to include the bot under Installed apps.

Assign this policy to users or teams for automatic installation.

Then share the app package with the organization by uploading it to a test catalog.



Application running successful:


This allows users within the organization to install and interact with the bot without manual addition.
